What are the exact react query overheads?

Does using react query introduce overhead of timers since it has to keep track of stale time, garbage collection on milliseconds precision?
Does it provide cache max limit size based on max number of queries or max storage allowed?

I am learning react query and started to wonder some points that nobody explains

Yes, it's a code that has to be executed. There is no cache limit by default, it uses a Map, but you can provide custom cache to do max number of queries if you want to. However, do you have a specific question about code for Stack overflow? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Thanks for the answer and pointing out my mistake. I will take care to ask valid questions according to the website and not only valid to me
